# Samsung Galaxy DUos - Balance Deductions

Tags: wi-fi

i am using Samsung Galaxy duos, Battery is consuming very much.it won't last more than 20 hours. It is also deducting my balance and heard mobile data could be a reason. What is mobile data? How can it deduct my balances?

Comment: If you go to `Settings > My device > Battery` what is using the most?

Answer (score 2):

Mobile data means Internet access on phone via mobile network. It costs you money when not on Internet plan. Turning it off is very easy. Open notification bar turn off Mobile Data (icon with 2 arrows one up one down) -or- open Settings>(More)Mobile networks> (uncheck) Mobile data (SIM1 & SIM2).